# How to create a popover coming from bottom of the screen for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, popover

I am looking for a way to implement [image: this kind of popover] this kind of popover.

Are there basic iOS commands to generate this style instead of the usual Arrow + Border popover that we see in XCode? Or is there an API to do this kind of thing.

The popover is coming up from the bottom of the screen, just like in the App Store animation sometimes.

Thank you

Comment: I think that's just a modal UIViewController with the modalPresentationStyle being set to UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Comment: God i was looking at the wrong place.. Thank you!

Comment: I wrote out more in an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create a custom `UIVIewController` with the modal presentation style set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`:

```
YourCustomViewController *customVC = [[YourCustomViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"YourCustomViewController" bundle:nil];

customVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self self presentViewController:customVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You will also have to create a toolbar and format it correctly with a "close" or "done" button that will dismiss the view controller